# How to pull a list of employees and their first job in Mongoose (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm fairly new to MongoDB, but I'm very familiar with SQL. I have collections of employees, jobs and acceptedjobs. For simplicity, let's say these are the fields:

```
EMPLOYEES
    _id
    name
    email

ACCEPTEDJOBS
    _id
    jobID
    employeeID

JOBS
    _id
    jobTitle
    startDate
```

An employee can be assigned to several jobs. How can I pull a list of every employee and the first job they had based on start date using Mongo?

I'm sure it somehow uses the populate options, but I haven't been able to make much progress with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what I needed by just plugging the both collection names and all the of relevant fields into the path and select fields of my populate options. I didn't think it would be that open ended (I didn't even have to tie which fields belong to which collection however they are all unique), but it seems to work.

Here's my populate options in case it helps anybody else:

```
  var populateOptions = {
    path: "job employee",
    select: "jobTitle startDate name email"
  };
```